# Django setup with sqlite3?

Tags: django

I am trying to follow the walkthrough on the django website and I downloaded sqlite and saved it in `C:\Windows\System32` folder.  When I edit the `settings.py` file what do I put for the `Name` field?  Do I have to set up a database?  The django literature say's that the API should take care of that for sqlite.  When I run `python manage.py syncdb` I just get a bunch of errors.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    Jason & Casey@SUPERBEAST ~/Desktop/mysite
$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 184, in
inner
    self._setup()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _set
up
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 93, in __in
it__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\Users\Jason & Casey\Desktop\mysite\mysite\settings.py", line 21
    }
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I haven't tried django under windows but python 2.7 surely comes with sqlite out of the box.

How to setup the database?

on the top of the file:

```
import os
```

then:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'yourdatabasename.db'),
    }
}
```

and finally a syncdb should do the trick.

If it doesn't work, mind to paste the traceback?

Comment: how do i paste the traceback? Take a pic and post it?

Comment: Windows cmd right?: Right click the title bar, edit > mark. Select the text and press enter. Then paste here.

Comment: Edit your question and add it there :)

Comment: Sounds like a stale }. Lemme create a pastebin with a demo settings.py that works and give it a run.  http://pastebin.com/v5fN4ifM Its working on me

Comment: that worked; I edited `'NAME':  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'test.db')' now where is the test.db saved?  is it in my django project folder that I set up?

Comment: `class Poll(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice`  I'm stuck on this part now; can you post what it should look like in pastebin?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is:

```
  File "c:\Users\Jason & Casey\Desktop\mysite\mysite\settings.py", line 21
    }
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Check the syntax a paren or brace hasn't been closed properly around `DATABASES`.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 4.0+ and Python 3.10+, you can use this code to set up your sqlite database.

on the top of the file:

```
import os
```

then:

```
DATABASE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': DATABASE_DIR,
    }
}
```

Obs: You can create sqlite database with a custom name

Example:

```
sqlite3 customName.db
```