# Error setting up South in a new Django project

Tags: django, django-south

I'm working on a new django project and following [this tutorial](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/10/24/starting-a-django-14-project-the-right-way/). I'm at the step "Using South for Database Migrations", attempting to run `python manage.py syncdb`, and I'm getting the following error:

```
(editorial)[hookedonwinter@hookedonwinter editorial (master *)]$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from south.management.commands.syncdb import Command as SyncCommand
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 18, in <module>
    from south import migration
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from south.models import MigrationHistory
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/south/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class MigrationHistory(models.Model):
  File "/Users/hookedonwinter/.virtualenvs/editorial/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 97, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Here is my settings.py file: https://gist.github.com/pjhoberman/5273653

There are no apps yet, just an empty project. I'm guessing it's a simple overlook on my part - any thoughts?

---

**Edit**

From the comments:

- I don't have any models yet. Just following that tutorial, I'm trying to start with South before I do any model work.
- Versions:

  - Django==1.5.1
  - South==0.7.6
- If I comment out south in settings.py, I get this error:

  `$ python manage.py syncdb`

  `TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases __init__() keywords must be strings`

---

**Edit2**

I started over and used django 1.4, and it works.

**Edit3**

I updated python to 2.7 and used django 1.5, and it all works as well.

Comment: can you share the models?. There could be something very trivial wrong in the way models are initialized

Comment: Doesn't look like he has any models or custom apps defined. Which version of Django/South?

Comment: Comment `south` in `INSTALLED_APPS` then run syncdb will get the error?

Comment: @karthikr No models. It's a totally clean install.

Comment: @JackShedd Django==1.5.1; South==0.7.6

Comment: @iMom0 `$ python manage.py syncdb
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() keywords must be strings`

Comment: @iMom0 There are no models - it's a totally fresh install

Comment: It only works with Python 2.7 and 3.3.

Answer (score 2):

The "TypeError" at the bottom is the solution. You get this error from Django 1.5 if you use a Python version lower than 2.6.5. There is a [Django bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18961) and a [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310373/django-server-can-not-run-why) on the issue. Arguably the error message is less than intuitive.

The OP is right, none of the answers solved this problem. The solutions are: 1) upgrade Python to 2.7, 2) downgrade Django to 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with that "~" character you have on your database setting. Try putting `#coding=utf-8` as the first or second line of your settings and see what happen.

If that doesn't resolve your problem, change the database filename for one on the same directory of `manage.py` file like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'databasename.sql',
    }
}
```

I tried making a new environment following that tutorial you post and i have no problem. But when i tried to use a database name as you were trying (the one with "~" in its name) i get this error:

```
(env) user@pc:/path >$  python manage.py syncdb --noinput
Syncing...
OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I bet that symbol is the root of your problem... Tell us if this solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

I updated python to 2.7 and used django 1.5, and it all works as well.

None of the answers actually solved the problem, so I'm answering it myself since I can't delete the question now that there's bounty.

Answer (score 0):

South is very well documented and i'm sure you'll be clear after going through it.

This is the tutorial.

http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/tutorial/part1.html

Still to make life simpler..

1) Download south and add it to your apps directory.
2) Add 'south' to INSTALLED APPS in settings.py
3) Run syncdb
4) $ ./manage.py schemamigration appname --initial
5) $ ./manage.py migrate appname

This is all you need for a very basic start.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't really answer the question, which is about the error message received during installation. But, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a DB config problem, try this. On the top of the file:

```
import os
```

then:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'yourdatabasename.db'),
    }
}
```

And finally a syncdb should do the trick. Also you can try "python manage.py reset south" to fix possible problems in the APP. If this doesn't work i suggest you start a new problem to discard other errors.

Original post: [Django setup with sqlite3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301419/django-setup-with-sqlite3)

Answer (score 0):

You need Python 2.6.5+ to run Django 1.5. That's why downgrading to Django 1.4 or upgrading to Python 2.7 was what solved your problem.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#python-compatibility